# serialização de struct recursivamente em C

Tags: c, banco-de-dados, linux, osx, unix

Atualmente estou trabalhando em grande projeto pessoal. É um banco de dados chave/valor portátil escrito em C.
[link projeto](https://github.com/GuilhermeGiacomoSimoes/a_simple_experimental_database) 
Porém, estou atravessando um grande problema, não consigo de forma alguma serializar uma struct para escrever em um arquivo com file_descriptor. 
Exemplo: 
Isso funciona perfeitamente

```
memcpy(destination, 10, sizeof(uint32_t));
ssize_t bytes_written = write(fd, destination, sizeof(uint32_t));
```

Porém, preciso serializar uma struct que contém array de structs dentro dela:

```
typedef struct Row {
    uint32_t id;
    char username[COLUMN_USERNAME_SIZE + 1];
    char email[COLUMN_EMAIL_SIZE + 1];
} Row;

typedef struct Page {
    int leaf;
    int elems;
    int current_address_memmory;
    struct Row* info[MAX_ELEMENTS];
    int childs[MAX_ELEMENTS + 1];
} Page;
```

E tentei isso da seguinte forma:

```
void static serialize_row(Row* source, void* destination) {
    memcpy(destination + ID_OFFSET, &(source->id), ID_SIZE);
    memcpy(destination + USERNAME_OFFSET, &(source->username), USERNAME_SIZE);
    memcpy(destination + EMAIL_OFFSET, &(source->email), EMAIL_SIZE);
}

void static serialize(Page* source, void* destination) {
    memcpy(destination + FOLHA_OFFSET, &(source->leaf), FOLHA_SIZE);
    memcpy(destination + ELEMS_OFFSET, &(source->elems), ELEMS_SIZE);
    memcpy(destination + ADDRESS_MEMMORY_OFFSET, &(source->current_address_memmory), ADDRESS_MEMMORY_SIZE);

    for(uint32_t index_info = 0; index_info < source->elems; index_info++) {
        void *row_serialize = malloc(sizeof(Row)); 
        serialize_row(&source->info[index_info], row_serialize);
        source->info[index_info] = row_serialize;
    }
}

const size_t OFFSET_PAGE = sizeof(Page); 
void *serialized_page = malloc(OFFSET_PAGE);
serialize(page, serialized_page);
ssize_t bytes_written = write(fd, serialized_page, OFFSET_PAGE);
```

Porém o problema que eu estou enfrentando é que o arquivo no qual eu gravo a struct serializada, está com dados aleatórios que não condiz com a struct serializada... Algo como isso: 
`.....`

Se eu der o comando `xxd -b file.db` a saída é isso:

```
00005dc0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ......
00005dc6: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ......
00005dcc: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ......
00005dd2: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ......
00005dd8: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ......
00005dde: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ......
00005de4: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ......
00005dea: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ......
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: poste um programa inteiro, compilável. Não entendi onde está a recursão. E não tem como ver se a struct tinha um outro conteúdo que não o mostrado. Escreva uma unidade de teste, preenchendo a estrutura e mostrando, serializando e gravando e lendo de volta e comparando. O simples. Um programa para testar a serialização.

Answer (score 0):

> serialização de struct recursivamente em C

Não parece haver recursão nesse caso

> Isso funciona perfeitamente

```
memcpy(destination, 10, sizeof(uint32_t));
ssize_t bytes_written = write(fd, destination, sizeof(uint32_t));
```

Não creio que funcione. Veja o protótipo de `memcpy()`. E imagino que pretendesse escrever `size_t`

```
typedef struct Row {
    uint32_t id;
    char username[COLUMN_USERNAME_SIZE + 1];
    char email[COLUMN_EMAIL_SIZE + 1];
} Row;

typedef struct Page {
    int leaf;
    int elems;
    int current_address_memmory;
    struct Row* info[MAX_ELEMENTS];
    int childs[MAX_ELEMENTS + 1];
} Page;
```

Essas estruturas deveriam ser anônimas. A grafia normal é `memory`. Se esse `int` deve conter um endereço de memória mesmo, entenda que C já tem um mecanismo para isso: use um ponteiro. E atente para o fato de que em x64 um ponteiro tem 8 bytes e um `int`apenas 4.

> Porém, preciso serializar uma struct que contém array de structs dentro dela

Mas a `struct` como mostrou não tem um array de structs dentro dela. Tem na verdade um `array` de ponteiros e isso faz toda a diferença: na hora de serializar precisa EXTRAIR apenas os dados, E na hora de recriar na memória precisa restaurar os ponteiros, criando novos registros e copiando os dados que estão no disco.

### Exemplo

Vou deixar um exemplo em C da maneira comum de escrever isso. Não vou gravar no disco porque não faz diferença no mecanismo, mas se achar importante eu posso incluir depois. Também vou simplificar um pouco as estruturas para não ficar muito longo.

#### `Row` e `Page` neste exemplo

```
typedef struct
{
    uint32_t id;
    char     username[F_SIZE];
    char     email[F_SIZE];

} Row;

typedef struct
{
    uint32_t leaf;
    uint32_t elems;
    uint32_t current_address_memory;
    Row*     info[N_ROWS];
    uint32_t childs[N_ROWS];

} Page;
```

Quase como em seu código, mas as duas `structs` são agora anônimas e tem menos constantes porque afinal é só um exemplo

#### `Page_data`: a `struct` a ser gravada no disco

```
typedef struct
{
    uint32_t len;
    char     p1[3 * sizeof(uint32_t)];
    char     p2[N_ROWS * sizeof(uint32_t)];
    struct
    {
        char flag;
        char data[sizeof(Row)];
    } infos[N_ROWS];

} Page_data;
```

Essa é a maneira comum de escrever isso: os primeiros 4 bytes indicam o tamanho do registro, que é variável porque não há razão para gravar em disco `Rows` que não estejam em uso. Então um `char flag` vale `0` apenas quando o ponteiro `info` do array for `NULL`. O tamanho `len` inclui o prório header e é o total de bytes a serem gravados no disco e assim dá pra gravar várias páginas em seguida no mesmo arquivo. Esse é um registro do tipo `variant record` do Pascal. `Page_data` tem o tamanho para conter o máximo de `Rows` possível, mas o registro pode não ter nenhuma.

`len`, `p1` e `p2` são os dados originais da página e estão sempre presentes. É a parte fixa do registro.

#### As funções do exemplo

```
int   disk_to_page(Page_data*, Page*);
int   page_to_disk(Page*, Page_data*);
```

a primeira função serializa os dados, extraindo os dados dos ponteiros e montando `Page_data` com os dados como devem ir para o disco. A segunda função recria uma `struct` `Page` com os dados como seriam lidos do disco.

```
int   page_cmp(Page*, Page*);
Page* page_factory();
Row*  row_factory();
int   show_page(Page*,const char*);
```

`page_cmp` compara campo a campo 2 `struct` `Page` e retorna `0` se são diferentes. Claro que se gravar um registro e ler de volta o resultado deve ser o mesmo então essa função faz o teste. `page_factory` e `row_factory` são *factory functions* que geram um registro preenchido e com valores conhecidos para `Page` e `Row`. `show_page` mostra os dados na tela. Tudo trivial. O código está abaixo.

#### `main()` para o exemplo

```
int main(void)
{
    srand(220501);
    Page* p = page_factory(); // random page data
    show_page(p, "\n[original data]");

    Page_data unpacked;
    page_to_disk(p, &unpacked); // serialize

    Page* other = page_factory(); // random page data
    disk_to_page(&unpacked, other); // deserialize
    show_page(other, "\n[unpacked data]");
    int res = page_cmp(p, other);
    if (res == 0)
        printf("\nserialize data does not match original\n");
    else
        printf("\nserialize/deserialize ok!\n");
    p=page_destroy(p);
    other=page_destroy(other);
    return 0;
}
```

O código gera uma `Page` mostra na tela e serializa. Depois extrai os dados em outra `Page` mostra na tela e compara as duas. Depois apaga tudo e encerra. Do modo como os dados são gerados, em torno de um terço dos ponteiros para `Row` serão `NULL`. Os campos de cada `Row` são incrementais para facilitar os testes. E reproduzíveis, claro.

#### Saída do exemplo

```
[original data]
leaf: 974, elems:940, addr:862
Childs:    0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
    0   id:1    user:User00001  E-00001@ma.il
    1   [NULL]
    2   [NULL]
    3   id:2    user:User00002  E-00002@ma.il
    4   [NULL]
    5   [NULL]
    6   id:3    user:User00003  E-00003@ma.il
    7   id:4    user:User00004  E-00004@ma.il
    8   id:5    user:User00005  E-00005@ma.il
    9   [NULL]

[unpacked data]
leaf: 974, elems:940, addr:862
Childs:    0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
    0   id:1    user:User00001  E-00001@ma.il
    1   [NULL]
    2   [NULL]
    3   id:2    user:User00002  E-00002@ma.il
    4   [NULL]
    5   [NULL]
    6   id:3    user:User00003  E-00003@ma.il
    7   id:4    user:User00004  E-00004@ma.il
    8   id:5    user:User00005  E-00005@ma.il
    9   [NULL]

serialize/deserialize ok!
```

### O código C

Abaixo os 3 arquivos do programa de teste.

Rodei isso em Windows porque era mais conveniente na hora em que eu tinha tempo, e não faz diferença. O que importa é entender que é preciso extrair os dados e eliminar os ponteiros na hora de gravar, e recriar tudo na ordem contrária na hora de ler do disco.

#### `sample.h`

```
#pragma pack(1)
#define F_SIZE 32
#define MAGIC_NUMBER (1000)
#define N_ROWS 10

#include <memory.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    uint32_t id;
    char     username[F_SIZE];
    char     email[F_SIZE];

} Row;

typedef struct
{
    uint32_t leaf;
    uint32_t elems;
    uint32_t current_address_memory;
    Row*     info[N_ROWS];
    uint32_t childs[N_ROWS];

} Page;

typedef struct
{
    uint32_t len;
    char     p1[3 * sizeof(uint32_t)];
    char     p2[N_ROWS * sizeof(uint32_t)];
    struct
    {
        char flag;
        char data[sizeof(Row)];
    } infos[N_ROWS];

} Page_data;

int   disk_to_page(Page_data*, Page*);
int   page_cmp(Page*, Page*);
Page* page_destroy(Page*);
Page* page_factory();
int   page_to_disk(Page*, Page_data*);
Row*  row_factory();
int   show_page(Page*,const char*);
```

#### `sample.c`

```
#pragma pack(1)
#include "sample.h"

//
// rebuild data from disk into a new page
// deserialize()
//
int disk_to_page(Page_data* packed, Page* page)
{
    if (page == NULL) return -1;
    if (packed == NULL) return -2;
    memset(page, 0, sizeof(Page));
    memcpy(&page->leaf, &packed->p1, 3 * sizeof(uint32_t));
    memcpy(
        &page->childs, &packed->p2,
        N_ROWS * sizeof(uint32_t));
    // now for the rows
    char* p = (char*)&packed->infos;
    // creates a new row for each one in disk
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < N_ROWS; i += 1)
        if (*p++ == 0)
            page->info[i] = NULL;
        else
        {
            page->info[i] = (Row*)malloc(sizeof(Row));
            memcpy(page->info[i], p, sizeof(Row));
            p += sizeof(Row);
        }
    return 0;
}

//
// extract all data from page into a
// variable length record
// serialize()
//
int page_to_disk(Page* page, Page_data* data)
{
    if (page == NULL) return -1;
    if (data == NULL) return -2;
    memset((void*)data, 0, sizeof(Page_data));
    uint32_t n_rows = 0;  // actual # of rows
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < N_ROWS; i += 1)
        if (page->info[i] != NULL) n_rows += 1;
    data->len = sizeof(uint32_t) + N_ROWS +
                (3 + N_ROWS) * sizeof(uint32_t) +
                n_rows * sizeof(Row);
    char* p = (char*)data;
    memcpy(
        p + sizeof(uint32_t), page, 3 * sizeof(uint32_t));
    p += 4 * sizeof(uint32_t);
    memcpy(p, &page->childs, N_ROWS * sizeof(uint32_t));
    // fixed part ok. Now for the rows
    p += N_ROWS * sizeof(uint32_t);
    // extract all row data
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < N_ROWS; i += 1)
        if (page->info[i] == NULL)
            *p++ = 0;  // just a NULL
        else
        {
            *p++ = 0xff;  // not NULL
            memcpy(p, page->info[i], sizeof(Row));
            p += sizeof(Row);  // pointer adjust
        }
    return 0;
}

//
// return 0 if pages are not exactly equal
//
int page_cmp(Page* A, Page* B)
{
    if (A == NULL) return 0;
    if (B == NULL) return 0;
    if (A->leaf != B->leaf) return 0;
    if (A->elems != B->elems) return 0;
    if (A->current_address_memory !=
        B->current_address_memory)
        return 0;
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < N_ROWS; i += 1)
    {
        if (A->info[i] == NULL)
        {
            if (B->info[i] != NULL) return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            if (B->info[i] == NULL) return 0;
            if ((A->info[i])->id != (B->info[i])->id)
                return 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < F_SIZE; j += 1)
                if (A->info[i]->username[j] !=
                    A->info[i]->username[j])
                    return 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < F_SIZE; j += 1)
                if (A->info[i]->email[j] !=
                    A->info[i]->email[j])
                    return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

//
// destroy all rows in a page and
// destroy the page
// return NULL to invalidate the pointer
//
Page* page_destroy(Page* page)
{
    if (page == NULL) return NULL;
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < N_ROWS; i += 1)
        if (page->info[i] != NULL) free(page->info[i]);
    free(page);
    return NULL;
}

//
// return a Page record with random data and random rows
//
Page* page_factory()
{
    Page* page = (Page*)malloc(sizeof(Page));
    memset(page, 0, sizeof(Page));
    page->leaf                   = rand() % MAGIC_NUMBER;
    page->elems                  = rand() % MAGIC_NUMBER;
    page->current_address_memory = rand() % MAGIC_NUMBER;
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < N_ROWS; i += 1)
    {
        if (rand() % 3 == 0)
            page->info[i] = row_factory();
        else
            page->info[i] = NULL;
        page->childs[i] = i;
    }
    return page;
}

//
// retorna Row con id a partir de 1
// username a partir de User00001
// email a partir de E-00001@ma.il
//
Row* row_factory()
{
    static uint32_t id  = 1;
    Row*            row = (Row*)malloc(sizeof(Row));
    memset(row, 0, sizeof(Row));
    sprintf(row->username, "User%05d", id);
    sprintf(row->email, "E-%05d@ma.il", id);
    row->id = id++;
    return row;
}

//
// show page data with optional title
//
int show_page(Page* page, const char* title)
{
    if (title != NULL) printf("%s\n", title);
    printf(
        "leaf: %d, elems:%d, addr:%d\n", page->leaf,
        page->elems, page->current_address_memory);
    printf("Childs: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < N_ROWS; i += 1)
        printf("%4d ", page->childs[i]);
    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < N_ROWS; i += 1)
        if (page->info[i] == NULL)
            printf("%5d\t[NULL]\n", i);
        else
            printf(
                "%5d\tid:%d\tuser:%s\t%s\n", i,
                page->info[i]->id, page->info[i]->username,
                page->info[i]->email);

    return 0;
}
```

#### `main.c`

```
#pragma pack(1)
#include <memory.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "sample.h"

int main(void)
{
    srand(220501);
    Page* p = page_factory(); // random page data
    show_page(p, "\n[original data]");

    Page_data unpacked;
    page_to_disk(p, &unpacked); // serialize

    Page* other = page_factory(); // random page data
    disk_to_page(&unpacked, other); // deserialize
    show_page(other, "\n[unpacked data]");
    int res = page_cmp(p, other);
    if (res == 0)
        printf("\nserialize data does not match original\n");
    else
        printf("\nserialize/deserialize ok!\n");
    p=page_destroy(p);
    other=page_destroy(other);
    return 0;
}

// https://pt.stackoverflow.com/
// questions/551127/serializa%c3%a7%c3%a3o
// -de-struct-recursivamente-em-c
```

Comment: Ah os vigilantes do SO! Então uma resposta que vai direto ao assunto, comenta o problema, apresenta um exemplo com código comentado e o resultado é `inútil`. E sobre aquela recomendação do próprio SO sobre apresentar relevantes sugestões para que pessoas menos preparadas (eu, nesse caso) possam melhorar suas respostas? Nada como o anonimato.

Comment: funcionou perfeitamente arfneto, muito obrigado.

Comment: :) Notou que a resposta foi marcada como inútil?